# Variable number of tabs in TabController

Tags: flutter

Having trouble creating a TabController where the number of Tabs varies based on input from Firebase (or any datasource). In my state, which utilizes the `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` I have the following:

```
@override void initState() {
  super.initState();
  //... 
  _controller = new TabController(vsync: this, length: tabs.length);
}
```

`tabs` is a List of objects that I use for the tab bar items and to build the widgets for each of the TabViews. However, I'm seeing odd behavior. The first odd bit is that tapping a tab triggers three events. Correctly registers the right tab index tapped, then oddly registers the original index and finally the original index where indexIsChanging gets set to 0 (presumably because the animation and change to that index has finished.

Also noticing that updating `tabs` in `setState` doesn't force the widget to rebuild. Any constructive thoughts?

Comment: can you try to create a new controller in setState, with the new number of tabs? Updating tabs has no influence on _controller because it is already initialised with a different number of tabs.

Comment: If you could provide a full working code sample that demonstrates the problem, that would make it easier for us to help you.